# Как совместить selenium с Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, telebot

Есть программа, которая управляет браузером и выводит в консоль значение по определенному ключу. Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы бот запрашивал у меня ключ, вставлял его в программу и отправлял запрос на сайт. Программа на selenium webdriver, библиотека бота telegrambotapi.

```
import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from art import tprint
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import sys


bot = telebot.TeleBot('2047977151:AAGeC9gKQLWGMVkbd56DarmK2cZxnCdh6rQ')




options = Options()
options.headless = True

url = "https://cerberus.vetrf.ru/cerberus/actualObject/pub/actualInfo/"

# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# guid = str (input('Введите GUID:'))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здарова, Сталкер!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['guid'])
    def guid_message():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)


def guid_chek():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши GIUD:')
    message.text == (guidi)
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    url = "https://cerberus.vetrf.ru/cerberus/actualObject/pub/actualInfo/"


    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys(guidi)
        # driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys('47b8c597-e073-4e53-a82e-da3eff32b389')
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Запрос выполняется...')
        # print ('stage1')
        time.sleep(1)
        if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="label label-success"][1]'):
            if True:
                tes1 = print('Подтвержден')
            
        elif driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="label label-warning"][1]'):
            if True:
                tes = print('Не подтвержден')

        elif driver. find_elements_by_tag_name("tbody"):
            if True:
                tes = print('Прощадка не найдена')
                
        time.sleep(1)
        result = print(tes1, tes)



    

    
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['guid'])
def guid_message():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправь GUID')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, guid_chek)
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! вы пишете, что хотите видеть, а что собственно сейчас происходит. Что вас не устраивает? Добавьте доп инфо в сам вопрос

Comment: согласен с комментарием выше. И зачем Вы после каждой проверки делаете дополнительную? Я про ```if True:```